# Kubernetes: invalid character looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to deploy a crd using kubectl. My CRD starts with something like

```
{{- if and (eq .Values.realm "aws") (.Values.crd) }}
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  annotations:
```

This throws an error:

```
error: error parsing ./charts/crds.yaml: json: offset 2: invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string
```

I am calling like this

```
kubectl apply --kubeconfig="/tmp/target" --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" -f ./charts/crds.yaml
```

Any idea how we can achieve this? I do this for other resources like deployment etc, and it doesn't have a problem.

Comment: What command exactly are you running?  Where exactly is this file located?  Helm won't run its templating engine on things that aren't located in a `crds` or `templates` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

That is invalid YAML and looks like part of a template that should be processed, generating the actual YAML to be used.
It could be part of a helm chart deducing from the content expressions.

If you want to use it without helm, you need to remove all template expressions and might want to use an online YAML validator to assist.